# If a random variable is a linear combination of another random variable does it have the same $\mu, \sigma^2$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If a random variable is a linear combination of another random variable does it have the same $\mu, \sigma^2$ ?

Is the variance the same but not the expectation? Please explain me by which by principles this hold or not.

Answer (score 4):

If by 'linear combination' of $X$ you mean a random variable of the type $Y=aX+b$ then mean of $Y$ is $a\mu +b$ and variance is $a^{2}\sigma^{2}$ where $\mu$ is the mean of $X$ and $\sigma ^{2}$ is its variance. These follow immediately from the definitions.